# Objeto HTML Canvas devuelve elemento diferente al pasar por JavaScript a Android

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, base64

Hace horas estoy tratando de resolver un comportamiento extraño al pasar un objeto HTMLCanvasElement hacia una función de Android.

En JavaScript tengo un HTMLCanvasElement el cual corresponde a un codigo de barras 2D tipo pdf417.
El caso es que necesito enviar dicho elemento hacia una app en Android, para que éste a su vez pueda representar la imagen. Para esto, convierto el elemento canvas en data URI con el método 'toDataURL'

El código JavaScript es:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('barcode'); // 'barcode' es un elemento <canvas>
Android.sendString(canvas.toDataURL());
```

Este elemento canvas me devuelve una imagen PNG de 358 x 176 px.

El código en Android es:

```
public void sendString(String texto) {  }
```

Si recojo el valor de 'texto' me devuelve igualmente un String en base64, pero al convertirlo a imagen PNG me devuelve la misma imagen, pero con el tamaño 686 x 352.

Es decir, al pasar el string base64 desde JavaScript a Android, me aumenta el tamaño de la imagen.

¿Alguien podría explicar por qué pasa esto?

Muchas gracias.